# Possible null reference argument ... when using <Nullable>enable</Nullable> in Net 6

Tags: c#

Using Net6 with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`in project definition I have

```
public class Options {
  public Dictionary<String, String> Accounts { get; set; } = new Dictionary<String, String>();
}

Options options = new Options();

List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>();

parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("doc", options?.Accounts["doc"]));
```

I am getting the error `Possible null reference argument for parameter 'value' in:

```
options?.Accounts["doc"];
```

I could use the following:

```
if (options.Accounts.ContainsKey("doc"))
  parameters..Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("to", options?.Accounts["doc"]!));
```

I added the `if` statement and the `!` ...

Is there another way to solve this without using the `if` statement?

Comment: The compiler is giving you a sensible warning: if you write `options?`, you're saying that `options` might be `null`, and so `options?.Accounts["doc"]` might end up `null` as well. But in the code you've given `options` is never null, so there's no need for the question mark.

Comment: Why do you use `options?` if `options` is `Options` and not `Options?`?

Comment: Also note that you could use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) (`??`) if the value of `options?` might be null but you want a record in `parameters` anyway: `parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("doc", options?.Accounts["doc"] ?? "Some default string value"));`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you want the value to be potentially null - it definitely *will* be null if `options` is null<sup>1</sup> - you should change the corresponding type argument to be nullable:

```cs
List<KeyValuePair<String, String?>> parameters =
    new List<KeyValuePair<String, String?>>();

parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String?>("doc", options?.Accounts["doc"]));
```

The compiler is basically helping you here - anyone consuming `parameters` could previously have assumed that the value part of each pair was non-null, given that it was a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. With the new code, they'll be forced/encouraged to handle null values.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming that in the real code, `options` is obtained elsewhere and might be null. If you're *really* assigning `options` a definitely-not-null value, you should just use `options.Accounts["doc"]`.